# How to replace a symbolic link with an equivalent hard link?

Tags: command-line, files, symlink, hard-link, ln

Having a (single, no batch filesystem processing needed) symlink, what a command line to use to turn it into a hard link to the same file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ln -f "$(readlink <symlink>)" <symlink>
```

Comment: as a command: 
`function soft_to_hard() { ln -f "$(dirname $1)/$(readlink $1)" $1;}`